# Skip post-integration-test execution when integration tests fail

Tags: maven, integration-testing

I would like to skip my `post-integration-test` execution when the integration tests failed to check for cause of failure. Currently, I have the following configuration for the `exec-maven-plugin`:

```
<execution>
    <id>docker-compose down</id>
    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>${docker.src}/stop_docker_compose.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a docker maven plugin there are some out there...

Comment: Do they provide that functionality? I obviously checked them out before settling on the exec-maven plugin. Many docker plugins don't support docker-compose well.